# Lxml not working in cloud function? what to do?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, beautifulsoup, lxml

I need to write a function that, when an XML file enters the S3 repository, would parse it. The difficulty is that all the dependencies must be located directly in the folder with the script itself and there is no way to use the Virtual Environment. And there is a difficulty with the fact that I in no way manage to get Beautiful Soup to see the parser:

> errorMessage ":" Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you
>   requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library? ",

Maybe someone faced the problem of local import of the lxml library. Please tell me how could I try to solve this problem?

Comment: Why can't you use a virtualenv? AWS's official docs for packaging python for lambda include instructions on how to do so with a virtualenv: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html

Comment: I recommend an XML parsing library, which is simple and lightweight, and does not rely on third-party libraries. It is SimplifiedDoc.

Comment: Thank you all very much. @dabingsou can you give me a link please? I can not find this library)

Comment: @Михаил Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo